# How to wire up 3DViewport in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have built a Model3DGroup in code behind and it works OK, but now I want to move my Model3DGroup to a ModelView in an MVVM Pattern.  The Model3DGroup is now set up as a property in the ModelView. 
So my question is: How do I change the code below to bind the Model3DGroup to the Viewport3D control?

```
                 <Viewport3D Name="MainViewport" ClipToBounds="True"  >
                    <Viewport3D.Camera>
                        <PerspectiveCamera
                            FarPlaneDistance="100"
                            LookDirection="-11,-10,-9"
                            UpDirection="0,1,0"
                            NearPlaneDistance="1"
                            Position="11,10,9"
                            FieldOfView="70" />
                    </Viewport3D.Camera>
                    <ModelUIElement3D ></ModelUIElement3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D>>
                        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                            <DirectionalLight
                                Color="White"
                                Direction="-2,-3,-1" />
                        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    </ModelVisual3D>
                </Viewport3D>
```

Thanks for your help!